# missing module when using pyinstaller to pack

Tags: python

I use windows 7 and python 2.7.
when I tried to pack the files into an .exe file using pyinstaller. In warnmian.txt, it says:

```
missing module named PyQt4 - imported by C:\Python27\lib\site- 
packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_qt4plugins.py
missing module named _sysconfigdata - imported by distutils.sysconfig
missing module named fcntl - imported by tempfile, subprocess
missing module named org - imported by copy
missing module named grp - imported by shutil, tarfile
missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath, shutil, tarfile
missing module named readline - imported by cmd, pdb
missing module named 'org.python' - imported by pickle
missing module named dbm - imported by whichdb, anydbm
missing module named gdbm - imported by anydbm
missing module named bsddb3 - imported by bsddb
missing module named _pybsddb - imported by bsddb, bsddb.db
missing module named riscosenviron - imported by os
missing module named riscospath - imported by os
missing module named riscos - imported by os
missing module named ce - imported by os
missing module named _emx_link - imported by os
missing module named os2 - imported by os
missing module named posix - imported by os
missing module named resource - imported by posix
```

how to fix it?

Comment: `pip install PyQt4`

Comment: I have already installed all the needed module. It shows error only when I pack it using pyinstaller